# Downgrade Windows 7 to XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation

I have programmer which uses parallel port to burn IC. It's software only supports Windows XP version.

I have a desktop with Intel Pentium Dual Core with ASUS chipset. The Windows 7 is installed on Desktop and works perfectly.

Unfortunately, the CD-DRIVE is broken, so only option I am left with is USB.

I created a Windows XP bootable USB. I inserted that into my desktop and select to boot from USB.

After a performing some test, it displays an error :-

```
No previous version of Windows NT can be found on your computer. 
Setup Cannot verify that you qualify to install this upgrade product.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you consider using XP in an emulator, virtual box for ex, instead of downgrading?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install Windows XP via an installation source that is designed to upgrade an older copy of Windows to Windows XP. But what you have instead is a newer copy Windows (i.e. Windows 7). In other words, you are trying to downgrade using a setup source only designed for upgrade.

You can install an older copy of Windows, say Windows 2000, first. Then, install Windows XP on top of it. Your only other option is to find a copy of Windows XP that supports installation on systems without an operating system, not just upgrade.

Of course, you might read on the web about another option: People who have Windows 7 Professional or Ultimate editions can install Windows XP Mode and get Windows XP that way. This option does not work for you because you are having a Pentium Dual Core that is incapable of running Windows XP Mode. Sorry.

Comment: He does need the parallel port - and not sure if you can pass that through a VM . XP mode won't. Virtualbox or vmware player/workstation *might*

Comment: I tried both the methods. Parallel port doesn't work on XP mode or VM. It needs full fledged OS.

Comment: I created Windows 2000 bootable disk, it didn't show  above mentioned  error. But instead showing another error : `setup cannot find end user licensing agreement (EULA)`.

Comment: Try copying the whole Windows 2000 setup to a folder on the hard disk drive, booting via a DOS prompt and running the Setup from there. To build a DOS prompt boot disk, use the Windows Explorer's Format command. There is "Make this disc bootable" option.

Comment: I used rufus to create bootable disk. Isn't that a better option?

Comment: It is an equally good option.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - A [USB to Parallel Port cable](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=usb%20to%20parallel&Submit=ENE) would work more then likely.  Its not guaranteed though, since I have used IC burners before, and they are very picky.